# Fedora Linux Unity error

Tags: linux, unity3d, fedora

Скачал юнити через хаб, при запуске выдает такую ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На одном форуме нашел, что якобы 2022 года версия работает стабильно, но ошибка не ушла. Подскажите как исправить. У меня стоит Fedora 38, openssl версии 3.0.8 (где-то видел, что версию понижали до 1)

Comment: На Fedora 34 устанавливается.